# Next.js Image component props onLoadingComplete not working?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-props, nextjs-image

I'm trying to get the **naturalWidth** and **naturalHeight** from **onLoadingComplete** props: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#onloadingcomplete but its not working? Perhaps I'm doing it wrong?

I have this function:

```
const handleImageLoad = (e) => {
  console.log("load", e);
};
```

then I have this  component from next.js

```
<Image
  onLoadingComplete={(e) => handleImageLoad(e)}
  className=""
  src={image["data_url"]}
  alt=""
  layout="fill"
  objectFit="contain"
/>
```

When the image is loaded, it doesn't do anything, if I try to console log, it works, but I don't know why its not working when I'm passing the `handleImageLoad`

```
onLoadingComplete={() => handleImageLoad()}
```

Comment: Can you please provide us a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? With your current description I am unable to reproduce the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-mahavira-9ygdi?file=/pages/layout-fill.js (Redirect to `/layout-fill` and scroll down to the second image to see logs.)

Comment: @brc-dd so I have a codesandbox where you can upload an image: https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-rain-d51sv?file=/pages/index.js, line 62-63

Comment: It appears that `onLoadingComplete` is not being triggered in case of data (base64) URI.  Also that line 63 thing is seemingly working because it is being simply called on each component mount/render. `() => {console.log('loaded')}` should work, which isn't. I guess you need to create a issue/discussion for this on the Next.js' GitHub. A workaround can be to create blob:// URLs instead of data URI. I am not sure though if it will work or not.

Comment: Can confirm that it is working on object URLs (`blob:`). https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-ellis-4htdl?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: @brc-dd can confirm as well. thanks! do you want to create an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** Fixed in v11.1.3-canary.33

---

It appears that the `next/image` component is not invoking `onLoadingComplete` handler in case provided `src` is a data URI. (And I can see you've opened an issue [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/29363) for the same.)

For now a workaround can be to use [Object URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL). If you wish, you can implement this quite directly. Refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459419/11613622) or the linked questions.

If you want to keep using `react-images-uploading`, you can use the methods mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12300351/11613622) and others, to convert the provided data URI to Object URL then pass it as `src` to `next/image`. Obviously, this will be more performance heavy operation that handling the uploaded file yourself.

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-ellis-4htdl?file=/pages/index.js

Just adding an alternative for the sake of completeness:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

const IndexPage = () => {
  const [src, setSrc] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSrc(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
    return true;
  };

  const handleImageLoad = (e) => {
    console.log("load", e);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="file"
        id="foo"
        name="foo"
        accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <div
        style={{
          marginTop: "1rem",
          width: 600,
          height: 600,
          backgroundColor: "blue",
          position: "relative"
        }}
      >
        {src?.length > 0 && (
          <Image
            onLoadingComplete={(e) => {
              handleImageLoad(e);
            }}
            src={src}
            alt=""
            layout="fill"
            objectFit="contain"
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default IndexPage;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Curious.. do you know of any other package that I should look into for image uploading if `react-images-uploading` might not be the best due to this issue?

Comment: @hellomello give a try to [`react-dropzone`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone). A demo here - https://react-dropzone.js.org/#section-previews

Comment: @hellomello A fix for this has been started by the Next.js team. After suitable test integrations it will be merged, and shall be there in the next patch release.

Comment: I saw! thank you! thanks for the suggestion to bring it up to the team!

Comment: I am using NextJS v12.1.6 but still doesn't work, not merged yet?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error, I was trying to make an image visible only if it was loaded.

It turns out if you set the style to `display:none` the `onLoadingComplete` is not invoked, as such:

```
<Image

    ...

    style={{
        display: "none"
    }}

    onLoadingComplete={(img) => { // this will not be invoked
        img.style.opacity = "block"
    }}
/>
```

To fix this I had to set a different style **and** define an empty `onError` function (without it the `onLoadingComplete` would be invoked regardless of image source being valid or invalid i.e. broken image)

```
<Image

    ...

    style={{
        visibility: "hidden",
        maxHeight: "0",
        maxWidth: "0"
    }}

    onLoadingComplete={(img) => {
        img.style.visibility = "visible"
        img.style.maxHeight = "none"
        img.style.maxWidth = "none"
    }}

    onError={() => {}}
/>
```

*This was tested for Next.js -v13.5.3*